# Conformal Map from Vertical Strip to Unit Disc

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I haven't found a similar question on here, though I suspect the question may be rather well-covered.

I want to find a conformal map from the vertical strip $\{z:-1<Re(z)<1\}$ **onto** the unit disc.

Under the exponential map the region is taken to the annulus with radii $e$ and $e^{-1}$, but I'm not sure how useful this will be.

Can anyone advise on what the conformal map may be?

Thanks.

Comment: Turn it to become horizontal. What does $\exp$ do now? Adjust the width as necessary.

Comment: Didn't work out the $z \mapsto iz$. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First apply $z \mapsto iz$ to map the strip onto the corresponding horizontal strip $-1 < \operatorname{Im} z < 1$.

Next step, apply $z \mapsto \exp(\frac{\pi z}2)$. This will give you the right half-plane $\operatorname{Re} z > 0$.

To finish off, the Möbius transformation $z \mapsto \dfrac{z-1}{z+1}$ takes the half-plane onto the unit disc.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't make the jump to apply $z \mapsto iz$.

Comment: Also known as $i \tan(\pi z/4)$.  So $\tan(\pi z/4)$ is a nice option.

Comment: @WimC, yes, but a lot harder to find without the intermediate steps, unless you're really good at complex trigonometric functions.

Comment: Why not using $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ which is the same as $iz$ ?

Comment: One could mention is that what you get is essentially the tangent function,  $i \cdot \tan(\pi z/4)$ to be precise.