# Showing a holomorphic function is bounded by |tan z|

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $U=\{|\Re z| < \frac{\pi}{4} \}$ and that $f$ maps 0 to 0, and $|f(z)|<1$ on $U$. Show $|f(z)| \le |\tan z|$ on $U$.

Comment: Have you tried mapping $U$ to the unit disk and applying Schwarz' lemma?

Comment: Yes, I tried that - seems like the natural thing to do but couldn't get it to work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393799/conformal-map-from-vertical-strip-to-unit-disc), it follows that $z \mapsto \tan(z)$ sends $U$ to the unit disk. Hence $g(w) = f(\arctan(w))$ maps from the unit disk to itself, and $g(0) = 0$, so by Schwarz' lemma, $|g(w)| \leq |w|$. Letting $w = \tan(z)$ for $z \in U$ gives $|f(z)| = |f(\arctan(\tan(z)))| = |g(\tan(z))| = |g(w)| \leq |w| = |\tan(z)|$, which is the claim.