# How does this complex function map πi/2 to => 0

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So I'm working on a question that asks

Find a conformal map that maps the horizontal strip $Im(z) ∈ (0,π)$ onto the unit disk $|z| < 1$
and maps $πi/2$ to 0
.

It says the solutions involve:

$f_1(z)=z-\frac{\pi}{2}$

I'm confused as to why this would even be included arrived as the first one doesn't work for mapping π/2 to 0:

$f_1(\frac{\pi i}{2})=\frac{\pi}{2}(i-1)≠0$

Shouldn't the proper mapping be
$f_1(z)=z-\frac{\pi i}{2}$

Comment: "$|z|$" is a modulus, not any sort of disk.  When you write "$Im$" is that the image of something or the imaginary part of something?  Also, why do you specify the "$Im$" twice with different prescriptions?

Comment: I also can’t figure out what you mean by $Im(z)\mapsto |z|>1,Im(z)\in(0,\pi)$

Comment: For: $Im(z) \mapsto |z| <1, Im (z) ∈ (0,π)$  I was trying to say that for the imaginary part of z in the region (0,π) Im (z) should map to the unit disk |z|<1. But I clarified the question a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

A solution *involves* $f_1(z) = z - \frac{\pi}{2}$, meaning that you probably have to find additional conformal maps $f_2,f_3,...$ in order to solve the exercise. So it is no surprise that $f_1(\frac{\pi}{2})\neq0$. Even if you were to define $f_1(z) = z-\frac{\pi i}{2}$, $f_1$ still wouldn't be a conformal map $A := \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \text{Im}(z) \in (0,\pi)\} \to \mathbb{D}$, so that doesn't really help.

However, I can give you a hint on how to solve the exercise differently (in my opinion the easiest way): Try to find conformal maps $f_1 : A \to \mathbb{H}$ and $f_2 : \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{D}$. Here, $\mathbb{H}$ denotes the upper half plane. Then, you can define $f : A \to \mathbb{D}$ as $f := f_2 \circ f_1$ and you'll see that indeed $f(\frac{\pi i}{2})=0$, as needed.

$f_1$ is a map that I'm sure you've used many times before, and if you're having trouble coming up with $f_2$ you can look up "Cayley transform/map". If you need additional hints, feel free to let me know.

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm a bit confused as to where the actual mapping came from/how the solution arrived at $f_1(z)=z-\frac {π}{2}$ in the first place? The only thing I could've thought of was to do something like this, which doesn't arrive at the same $f_1$: 

$ { f(z)=Az+iB | A, B ∈ \mathbb{R} } $
Where A
Take B to be -1
$
  f(\frac {iπ}{2})=0$
  $\frac {Aiπ}{2}=i$
  $A = \frac {2}{π}$
$∴ f_1(z)=\frac {2z}{π}-i$
   $  -1≤Im(f_1(z))≤1
$

Comment: @user3655510 Defining $f_1$ as $f_1(z)=\frac{2}{\pi}z-i$ is a good place to start! However, it is important that $-1<\text{Im}(f_1(z))<1$, and not $-1\leq\text{Im}(f_1(z))\leq1$ (it's important that you consider *open* sets). Then, to finish, I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393799/conformal-map-from-vertical-strip-to-unit-disc) might help you.