Find the conformal automorphism group on U
Let $U=\{z\in \mathbb{C}~:~ 1<Re(z)<2\}$. Give an explicit description of Aut$(U)$.
I self studying complex analysis and have no idea on how to approach this problem.
I have some idea:
For each $f\in $Aut$(U)$ we can post compose with $ \dfrac{i-z}{i+z} \circ e^{z}\circ iz\circ f(z)$, denote it by $g$. Then $g : U \to \mathbb{D}_1(0)$. So I have the following
$$ \dfrac{i-if(z)}{i+if(z)}= \dfrac{1-f(z)}{1+f(z)}=g(z)$$
Solve for $f$ gives me
$$f(z)= \dfrac{1-g(z)}{g(z)}$$
with $0<$Re$(g(z))<1/3$ ? So everything in Aut$(U)$ looks like this?
Any help would be appreciated!
Also, is there any list of conformal maps I can find online that maps different subregions of $\mathbb{C}$ to the unit disc, I would like to learn them so I can solve problem like this efficiently, but I couldnt find anything.

This should help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/393799/42969

@MartinR Thank you it helped. Does the edited version seems reasonable? Thanks!

Do you know the theorem characterizing conformal automorphisms of the Poincare disc?

@LeeMosher I dont know what a Poincare disc is, the text book I am reading covers Aut on upper half plane, unit dics , C and riemann sphere.

The Poincaré disc is the same thing as the unit disc in $\mathbb C$. Do you know the theorem characterizing conformal automorphisms of the unit disc in $\mathbb C$?

Or the theorem characterizing conformal automorphisms of the upper half plane? Either one of those two characterization theorems would apply directly to give a simple solution to your problem.

@LeeMosher Thank you, so I looked up the characterization of automorphism on Upper half plane and they are mobius transformation with $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ and $ad-bc>0$. Now, I see $e^z\circ iz\circ f(z) = \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with some algebra I have $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{i}\log( \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d})$ but this doesnt look like a rotation. Could you point my mistake out? thanks

The only automorphisms are rotations. The method suggested in the comments, of pulling things back to the disk, will work. Though it will involve some formula manipulation and a bit of linear algebra (to determine which automorphisms can be pushed back down). I find it easier and cleaner to reduce the question to the automorphisms of the complex plane with Schwarz reflection.
Let $f$ be a conformal automorphism of the annulus $U$. Note that $f$ extends to a continuous map from the closed annulus $\overline{U}$ to $\overline{U}$ that takes boundary components to themselves. (If you don't know a general result that implies this, it can also be proved by pulling back to covers and citing the classification of automorphisms of the disk or upper half-plane).
The Schwarz reflection principle applied to each boundary component (moved from the upper half plane to the annulus, by means of one of the maps discussed above) extends $f$ to a conformal automorphism of the larger annulus $U_2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 1/2 < |z| < 4\}$.
Repeating this process extends $f$ to a conformal automorphism from $(\mathbb{C} - \{0\}) \to (\mathbb{C} - \{0\})$. The removable singularity theorem implies $f$ extends to an entire function that sends the circle $|z| = 1$ to itself. All conformal automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ are of the form $z \mapsto \lambda z + c$. The only such maps that preserve the unit circle are rotations. So $f$ is a rotation.
